# Create a Bounce Effect on UIView when it is touched

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimation-curve

How do we create a bounce effect when user touch a UIView?

1. User touch and hold the view, the view shrink in size.
2. When user release it, it pops back and bounce to it's normal size.

I have no idea how to explain this. But i would say It's like the one on the Tinder user's picture when it's pressed..

Answer (score 0):

To have that effect you can you can use [UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicBehavior_Class/index.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) is a sample code provided by Apple itself. You can use [UIDynamicAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/) and [UIAttachmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAttachmentBehavior_Class/) to achieve what you want.

You can also use `UIControlEventTouchDown` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event of `UIButton` to handle this case, if not `UIDynamicBehavior`.

Thanks, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For handling the touch gesture i would suggest adding a Long Press Gesture Recogniser to the view in question. Control drag to create a function like this

```
@IBAction func longPress(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
        {
            //Shrink animation
        }               
        else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
        {
            //Bounce animation
        }
    }
```

I'm not that familiair with creating my own animations, but I have used this library called Spring (https://github.com/MengTo/Spring) in the past which was really easy to install and use to add good looking animations.